# Only one icon gets loaded on Google Chrome whereas all the icons get loaded on Safari

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, features, mapping, icon

I am using OpenLayers to display a map on my browser. I am getting data from a JSON file and using it to add icons on my map. The code works well on Safari (all icons get loaded) but when I try to use it on Google Chrome only one icon gets loaded. Also, on Google Chrome when I refresh, sometimes that one icon disappears as well. I am not sure how to fix this. The code is below.

> map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import "ol/ol.css";
import Feature from "ol/Feature";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import Point from "ol/geom/Point";
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import Stamen from "ol/source/Stamen";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { Icon, Style } from "ol/style";

import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "white"];
var index = 0;
var activeColor = "red";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  iconFeatures:Feature = [];
  map: Map;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){



 }
  ngOnInit(){
this.map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: document.getElementById("map"),
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3
  })
});


this.http.get("../../assets/icons.json").subscribe(icons=>{
  console.log("icons: ",icons)
  for(let icon in icons){
    var iconFeature = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(icons[icon].coordinates),
      scale: 0.01,
      imgSrc: "assets/non_transparent.jpg"
    });
    iconFeature.set("style",this.createStyle(iconFeature.get("imgSrc"),undefined));
    this.iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
  };
  this.createIconSource();
});
}

  public createIconSource(){
var vectorSource= new VectorSource({
  features:this.iconFeatures,
  wrapX: false

});

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: function(feature) {
    if (feature.get("color") !== activeColor) {
      var initStyle = feature.get("initStyle");
      if (!initStyle) {
        initStyle = feature.get("style");
        feature.set("initStyle", initStyle);
      }
      var image = initStyle.getImage().getImage();

      if (image.width > 0) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //this method returns an object that provides methods and properties for drawing on the canvas. eg: text, line, boxes, circles, and more

        var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
        s = 100,  // thickness scale
        i = 0,  // iterator
        x = s,  // final position
        y = s;

        // fill with color


        //set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
        canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
        canvas.height = image.height + s + s ;

        // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
        for (; i < dArr.length; i += 2){
          ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i] * s, y + dArr[i + 1] * s);
        }

        // fill with color
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // draw original image in normal mode
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y); //, image.width, image.height);

        //create new openlayers icon style from canvas
        var newStyle = new Style({
          image: new Icon(
            /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
              crossOrigin: "anonymous",
              src: undefined,
              img: canvas,
              imgSize: canvas
                ? [canvas.width, canvas.height]
                : undefined,
              scale: feature.get('scale')
            })
          )
        });
        feature.set("style", newStyle);
        feature.set("color", activeColor);
      }
    }
    return feature.get("style");
  }
});
this.map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  }

  public createStyle(src, img) {
    return new Style({
      image: new Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.96],
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",
        src: src,
        img: img,
        imgSize: img ? [img.width, img.height] : undefined,
        scale: 0.1
      })
    });
  }

}
```

> icons.json

```
{
  "Icon0":{
    "coordinates": [0,0]
  },
  "Icon1":{
        "coordinates": [300000, 300000]
  },
  "Icon2":{
    "coordinates": [5000000, 5000000]
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger (console, network)?

Comment: There are no errors in browser debugger but Google chrome gives me this warning: "[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 53ms"